# How to take a screenshot/bitmap of the area behind an ImageView/any UI component in Android?

Tags: android, bitmap, screenshot, blur

let's suppose I have an ImageView, Grid or whatever control. What I want to do is take a screenshot of what's behind this control, let's say another controls that hold a background image or anything there could be. Is there any way I could do this? I thought of the getDrawingCache(); method but that would take the top control too.

I want to do this so I can make the blurry transparent effect of what is behind of my top controls. I already have a blurring method, I just need to take the exact picture of the background. Any help will be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the `getDrawingCache()` method on any view, so if you have a reference to your background view it should work with something like this:

```
<your background view>.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);
Bitmap contentBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(<your background view>.getDrawingCache());
<your background view>.setDrawingCacheEnabled(false);
```

The `contentBitmap` should now contain a bitmap of what was in that view.

Comment: Thanks! By appContent what do you mean? The same background view?

Comment: Yes, it's the same backgound view, I missed that one when I renamed it

Answer (score 1):

```
public static Bitmap getViewBitmap(View v) {
    v.clearFocus();
    v.setPressed(false);

    boolean willNotCache = v.willNotCacheDrawing();
    v.setWillNotCacheDrawing(false);

    // Reset the drawing cache background color to fully transparent
    // for the duration of this operation
    int color = v.getDrawingCacheBackgroundColor();
    v.setDrawingCacheBackgroundColor(0);

    if (color != 0) {
        v.destroyDrawingCache();
    }
    v.buildDrawingCache();
    Bitmap cacheBitmap = v.getDrawingCache();
    if (cacheBitmap == null) {
        Log.e(tag, "failed getViewBitmap(" + v + ")", new RuntimeException());
        return null;
    }

    Bitmap bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(cacheBitmap);

    // Restore the view
    v.destroyDrawingCache();
    v.setWillNotCacheDrawing(willNotCache);
    v.setDrawingCacheBackgroundColor(color);

    return bitmap;
}
```